# Mock Data with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, dagger-2

I am trying to mock data with Mockito and getting NPE. Here is the sample code I am trying to test:

```html
public class MyPresenter implements Contract.Presenter {
  @Inject
  MyManager myManager;

  @Override
  public void doSomething(Data data) {
    myManager.doSomething(data);
  }
}

public class MyPresenterTest {

  @Mock
  private MyManager myManager; 

  @InjectMocks
  private MyPresenter myPresenter;

  @Before
  public void setup(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void doSomethingTest(){
    Data data = new Data();
    myPresenter.doSomething(data);
    verify(myManager).doSomething(data);
  }
}
```

NPE is coming at the following line in the MyPresenter class.

myManager.doSomething(data);

@Inject in MyPresenter injects the object using Dagger 2.

Could anyone please help ?

Comment: You have not added the Dagger component which injects these dependencies.

Comment: Will that not be handled by Mockito ? What I am expecting is Mockito will create mock objects and inject it into my presenter class with annotation @InjectMocks. And that object should be enough to test the calls to its methods. Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito injects mocks only to the constructor, leaving the fields undefined. In order to test it properly, one needs to initialize the class with the constructor parameter and Mockito by hand. It will work if you can add a constructor which takes in MyManager instance such as -

```
public class MyPresenter implements Contract.Presenter {
  @Inject
  MyManager myManager;

  public MyPresenter(MyManager myManager){ // constructor is required for mocikto to inject your fields.
     this.myManager = manager
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething(Data data) {
     myManager.doSomething(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.